# Is it safe to delete laravel.log?

Tags: php, laravel

I found out that laravel.log took half of the space in my hosting. Since I'm using shared hosting, is it safe to just delete it from file manager? Is it true that it will be created if it's not there? Thank you

Comment: So rename file and try.

Comment: Rename it. Try it and see. Can always undo. Read up on laravel logging: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging Sounds like you might want to tweak levels for production, or clean up some of those notices.

Comment: thank you, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.
I recommend setting up a third-party logging service for production, so you can get notified of critical notifications directly, and not use disk space in (most of the time) irrelevant logs.

We only use the laravel.log in development environments, and it is properly .gitignore(d) in the repo.